# Responsive background jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, responsive-design

I'm trying to make responsive background slideshow in custom Drupal theme. Slideshow part is covered by Drupal's modules (Views, Slideshow), and images are positioned by CSS. Now, I have written a simple jQuery code that makes images stretch and fill the screen. I was thinking that everything is OK, until I tested it in IE. Later, I discovered more issues. So, here they are:

```
1. In IE9, this code works only on first image, others keep their original sizes. 
2. In IE8 there is no background images at all on the screen. 
3. In Firefox, after a while, browser crash.
```

Something is probably terribly wrong with this little code of mine, but I cannot find what:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    stretchBg();
    var windowWidth;
    var windowHeight;
    var imageWidth;
    var ratio;
    var imageHeight;
    function stretchBg() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('#background img').each(function() {
  imageWidth =  $(this).attr('width');
  ratio = parseFloat(windowWidth / imageWidth).toFixed(2);
  imageHeight = $(this).attr('height') * ratio;
  if(windowHeight <= imageHeight) {
    $(this).attr('width', windowWidth);
    } else {
    $(this).attr('height', windowHeight);
  }
}); 
    }  
    $(window).resize(function() {
    stretchBg();
    });
    });
```

Note: I am using attr() and not width() for the images because they are hidden with display:none property and their dimensions cannot be retrieved before they are loaded.

**Thank you very much, I highly appreciate your help.**